# What type of unbrako screw is this?

Tags: screws

I need some spare screws like the one in the picture, but I have no idea what it’s called.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I would start with "hex socket bolt with shoulder"

Comment: Looks more like a torx to me. I would search for "pan head torx bolt with shoulder". Can you take another picture of the socket? Also, to get an exact replacement, you will likely need calipers to get accurate measurements.

Comment: -1 for missing focus, but +1 for including a curly hair.

Comment: A straight on shot of the head would be helpfull I thought it was a tamper resistant screw so 3 responses with different guesses because we can't quite make out the type, but is is a shoulder bolt / screw.

Comment: How do you know what brand it is?

Comment: What is it for?

Answer (score 1):

The nearest match in [Unbrako's product line](http://www.unbrako.com/socket-screws) is probably the "socket head shoulder screw" but its not an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

A search on Google did result on tons of results using the search words "shoulder bolt", none are an exact match, but if you filter results by images only, you can sort out the replacement that will work best for you.